# How do I create variable paths using e4X?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, e4x

I need to know how I can parse a variable path in Flex 3 & e4X.  For example, I have two XML strings where the name of one element is the only difference.

```
<NameOfRoot>
    <NameOfChild1>
        <data>1</data>
    </NameOfChild1>
</NameOfRoot>

<NameOfRoot>
    <NameOfChild2>
        <data>2</data>
    </NameOfChild2>
</NameOfRoot>
```

Currently I am accessing variables like this:

```
var data1:String = NameOfRoot.*::NameOfChild1.*::data;
var data2:String = NameOfRoot.*::NameOfChild2.*::data;
```

I would rather make this task more abstract so that if "NameOfChild3" is introduced I do not need to update the code.  For example:

```
var data:String = NameOfRoot.*::{variable}.*::data;
```

Does anyone have insights into how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ".*." operation will work.  I wonder if this is the easiest way to handle this problem.

```
var data:String = NameOfRoot.*.*::data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`child`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XML.html#child%28%29) property (LiveDocs example [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/13_Working_with_XML_08.html#130527)):

```
var tagName:String = "NameOfChild1";
var data:String = NameOfRoot.child(tagName).data;
```

That's with no namespacing--not sure whether it's necessary in your case, but I assume you'd add some `*::`'s?

Answer (score 1):

this also works:

```
var data:String = NameOfRoot..data;
```

but if you have more than 1 data node you'll have to sort some stuff out.